# I did all explanation. Can you just teach me how to calculate this interior product?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Orient the unit sphere $S^n$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ as the boundary of the closed unit ball.

Show that an orientation form on $S^n$ is

$w=\sum _{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}x^i dx^1∧...∧dx^i∧...∧dx^{n+1}$

I think that

I need to calculate i$_{X}(dx^1 ∧···∧dx^{n+1})$.

Let's write $X=\sum x^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$

Then I obtain that 
$i_{\sum x^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}(dx^1 ∧···∧dx^{n+1})$

After here, How to calculate this? I have my final exam tommorow. So I need to learn this calculation. Please show me. Thank you so much:)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Some of the folks in the MSE community get offended by help me with last minute questions. Just some friendly advice. Regards

Comment: Thank you for advice. Can you show me please? Thank you:) @Amzoti

Comment: As @Amzoti is much nicer than I, I will offer more blunt advice: the more desperate you seem, the more demanding you are, the less likely that anyone will want to take their time to look at your problem.  Keep in mind: you have not paid for a service.  People are here to enjoy themselves, not see too it that you pass your exam tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the results that for 1 form $ \omega \in \Omega^1(M) $ you have $i_X(\omega) = \omega(X)$ and in general for any two forms $\omega,\eta $ you have $ i_X(\omega\wedge \eta) = (i_X\omega)\wedge \eta + (-1)^{\deg(\omega)}\omega\wedge (i_X\eta) $. Using these two it is easy to prove for 1 forms $ \omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_k \in \Omega^1(M) $ you have (the hat implies that is omitted)
$$ i_X(\omega_1\wedge\omega_2\wedge...\wedge \omega_k) = \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1} \omega_i(X)(\omega_1\wedge\omega_2\wedge...\hat{\omega_i}...\wedge \omega_k) $$
So you have your answer.

Comment: And I should mention that you have asked the question in a most inappropriate time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am grateful of you. Thank you a lot:))

Comment: Why do User28337447 ask questions inapproiate time? @smiley06

Comment: I agree with B11b. Why? @smiley06

Comment: @B11b  Desperate questions on the day before the exams and demanding for answers are seemingly inappropriate enough...

Comment: Okay. I think so. But nothing to do. By the way good solution. @smiley06